# How to arc line over swim lane?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Does anyone know how to set Draw.io to support line jump arcs over swim lane borders? As per the attached screenshot, the jumps work fine elsewhere.

I also tried sending the swim lane thing to the back layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jumps only work between orthogonal connectors, the edges of swimlanes are not connector, they are not designed to trigger a jump.